# PGP-Encrypt system-generated notifications

Tags: plugins, notifications, encryption

I was wondering if there is a way to get Wordpress to encrypt notification mails ("Please moderate ..." and so on) using PGP.

I have found a bunch of plugins providing PGP-encrypted eMail forms, but that's not what I was looking for, as I want the system mails to be encrypted, not the user mails.

Is there any plugin or modification that does this that I have not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small [PGP plugin by Tim Nash](https://gist.github.com/timnashcouk/dd1ff318489f6bfd8743) on GitHub (but it's not in the official Wordpress repository, it needs to be manually copied to wordpress plugin directory). It's a wrapper using php-pgp library for encryption. The article where I found this link is ["Encrypting emails with PGP and WordPress"](https://timnash.co.uk/wordpress-pgp-email/). This is the only Wordpress solution I have found so far.

I was also [digging into the subject](http://buli.waw.pl/wordpress-openpgp-emails/) and I'm trying more generic approach - extending PHPMailer to support PGP encryption. However, this requires some more testing to support email in both text and html format, PGP/MIME, attachments etc. so this is not ready to be published yet.